# Facebook Opengraph tags correct on site but wrong on Facebook Linter

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

As you can see from the debug at the top of my blog: http://www.alexchin.co.uk/archives/2485 the OG meta tag is pulling a thumbnail image for the page and assigning it to the OG meta image tag.

However, when you go to Facebook Linter or try to share the link, the default image for the page turns up. This used to work, but now has stopped working.

In addition, Facebook Linter is showing that I have assiged a fb:page_id meta tag to the page, which I did earlier yesterday but have now deleted.

Are the Facebook servers just on a bit of a lag or do you think I have done something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I see everything fine in both [Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.alexchin.co.uk/) and Facebook share preview, it was probably just a momentary lag

http://phpcode.eu/images/1317824154.png

> In addition, Facebook Linter is showing that I have assiged a fb:page_id meta tag to the page, which I did earlier yesterday but have now deleted.

they're caching it all. It will take a while.

Comment: The image is meant to be the thumbnail for the video image? Please see the debug at the top of the page.

Comment: @AlexChin: you said it don't work. It works for me. For your second problem, I just said you have to wait a bit before cache expires